# Authentication session in Webview

Tags: macos, cocoa, authentication, cookies, webview

I'm working on an OS X app where the user can connect to its accounts on different external services (in OAuth).
To do so, I need to open a page of my API (a Rails app) in a Webview, which will redirect the user to the service to connect. At the end of the process, the user will be redirected again on my API, which will tell him if the connection has worked fine or not.

Therefore, the user needs to be authenticated on my API, both before and after the OAuth process on the external service website.
When I open the Webview, the user is authenticated thanks to an access token as a parameter of the url, and the redirection to the external service works fine.
But very often, when the user is redirected on my API after the connection, he is not authenticated anymore (but sometimes it works).

When I check the existing cookies for my app through

```
[[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] cookiesForURL:]
```

I do have a session cookie for my API:

```
<NSHTTPCookie version:0 name:"_..._api_session" value:... expiresDate:(null) created:2014-02-12 19:16:00 +0000 (4.13925e+08) sessionOnly:TRUE domain:... path:"/" isSecure:FALSE>
```

It just doesn't seem to be sufficient to keep the user authenticated.

Where this can come from? 
It somehow seems to be related to the Webview, because when I do this whole process by sending the user to an external browser, it works fine.
Does the Webview have a specific way to handle session cookies?

I don't know if I'm being specific enough, please ask if you want other details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found out what the problem was.

My app communicates with my API through a permanent sync process, and needs to be authenticated with an access_token. I use AFNetworking for that, which creates a session cookie in the app container.

When I authenticate again in the Webview, it also creates a cookie session. Somehow, the cookies are in conflict and break the session.

I just told AFNetworking not to use cookies to avoid that, and it worked.